# Where can I get a replacement DS Lite battery in Germany?

Tags: nintendo-ds

I'm looking for a replacement battery for my DS Lite. I recently moved from the United States to Germany; back in the US, [the Nintendo Store offers a replacement DS Lite battery](http://store.nintendo.com/webapp/wcs/stores/servlet/ProductDisplay?catalogId=10001&storeId=10001&langId=-1&currency=USD&ignoreCrumbs=N&crumb1=%253CA%2BHREF%253D%2522javascript%253APassOn%2528%2527C%2527%252C%2B%2527CategoryDisplay%2527%252C%252762205%2527%252C%2B%2527N%2527%2529%253B%2522%253ENintendo%2BDS%253C%252FA%253E&crumb1Ignore=&crumb2=%253CA%2BHREF%253D%2522javascript%253APassOn%2528%2527X%2527%252C%2B%2527ChooseView%2527%252C%2527%2527%252C%2B%2527%2527%2529%253B%2522%253ENintendo%2BDS%2BLite%253C%252FA%253E&crumb2Ignore=&crumb3=%253CA%2BHREF%253D%2522javascript%253APassOn%2528%2527C%2527%252C%2B%2527CategoryDisplay%2527%252C%252762209%2527%252C%2B%2527N%2527%2529%253B%2522%253EParts%2B%2526%2BAccessories%253C%252FA%253E&crumb3Ignore=&translateFrom=%C3%88%C3%89%C3%87&translateTo=EEC&usrSearchText=&searchText=&selSrchType=&page=&view=&productId=108205&categoryId=62209&lastAction=ProductDisplay&orderTotal=null&tranId=0&jktranid=&rpComment=&dropOff=). However, that would be subject to insane shipping charges as well as customs fees and delays.

However, I cannot find any equivalent store on the [Nintendo Germany](http://www.nintendo.de) website, nor the [Nintendo UK](http://www.nintendo.co.uk/) site, which would at least keep shipping within the EEC (and it's in a language I know). They do offer repair services which can replace the battery, but these are much more expensive and won't accept my US-origin DS Lite anyway.

The local GameStop and Saturn do not have any DS Lite batteries. Amazon.de and Amazon.co.uk both have plenty of third-party batteries, most of which have bad reviews, with claims that the batteries do not fit, are labelled incorrectly, and just plain don't last long. I'd rather not take my chances with tiny containers of potential energy, so these don't seem like a good choice.

Is there anywhere within Germany (or barring that, within the EEC) where I can order a good DS Lite battery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this page](http://www.nintendo.de/NOE/de_DE/support/nintendo_ds_lite_159_128.html) you can order one from Nintendo for 11 EUR + 3,50 EUR shipping. They don't have an online shop though, you'll have to contact them directly (see [contact information](http://www.nintendo.de/NOE/de_DE/service/contact_2095.html), Konsumentenberatung: mail: info@nintendo.de) and hope they'll understand english.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking for "Battery" and "Batterie", didn't know "Akku", which my wife just explained to me.

Comment: Batterie is mostly used for non-recharchable batteries. "Akku" is used for everything you can recharge.